# How can I use startswith without specifying a certain string? Is there any alternative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I would like to apply `vocal_start` to so many different variables and i can't handle them all and i wouldn't always repeat `startswith`. So I don't want to write `variable1.startswith(("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))`, but i would like to apply startswith(("a", "e", "i", " o", "u")) directly to all variables without specifying `variable1.startswith` (something similar to my code). I wouldn't always repeat `startswith`

I guess using `startswith` is only like this (variable1.startswith), so is there anything else I can use? I need something like my code, but not with startswith (or I'd like to use startswith differently if possible)

```
vocal_start = startswith(("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))

variable1 = "open"

#Only for Test
if variable1 == vocal_start:
    print("correct")
```

In the code, of course, I get the `NameError: name 'startswith' is not defined` because I didn't specify variable1.startswith(("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")), but as I said, I don't want to go this route

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with something like `if variable1.startswith(vowels):` where vowels is a tuple or whatever

Comment: @wim Can you explain better please?

Comment: @jasonharper I wouldn't always repeat startswith. For this reason I was looking for something different. Your answer is good, but I should always write startswith(vocal_start). Do you have other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @EvangelosDellas: So you're just trying to find some way to call `.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))` on a variable without spelling that out each time? How is `if if variable1 == vocal_start:` a meaningful improvement on `if variable1.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')):`, or if you want to define the `tuple` elsewhere, `vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')` at top-level somewhere, then `if variable1.startswith(vowels):`?

Comment: Why do you have many variables in the first place?

Comment: And how many is "so many"?

Comment: @KellyBundy In the question code, to simplify, I wrote only variable1. Actually I have 20 or 30 variables: they are grammar variables

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to have that many variables instead of *one* list or dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your desired form to work if you don't mind writing really obscure code. Write a class whose `__eq__` does what you want and then use an instance of that class for your compare.

```
>>> class Startswith:
...     def __eq__(self, rhs):
...             return rhs.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))
... 
>>> startswith = Startswith()
>>> "abcd" == startswith
True
>>> "xxx" == startswith
False
```

Comment: Why did you write __eq__ and rhs? What do they mean? (I know what their function is, but I didn't understand why you literally used these two words)

Comment: @EvangelosDellas: `__eq__` is the name of the special method invoked by `==` (it's how you overload equality tests, you can't use random names). `rhs` is just by convention (stands for "right-hand side", since it's the other object being compared here, though ironically, it could be the left-hand side as well, thanks to how operator overloading reflection works).

Comment: Equality comparisons should never raise exceptions.  This will make `AttributeError` other obj doesn't have a `startswith` method.  `rhs` is a bad variable name, because the other may actually be on `rhs` or `lhs`.

Answer (score 4):

If the values to check are all 1 character (or all the same length) you could use the `in` operator with a substring to get the first letter(s):

```
if variable[:1] in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
   ...
```

or

```
if variable[:1] in "aeiou":
   ...
```

Comment: @Alain T. The values can have different lengths, for example: ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u") or even ("ore", "one", "ire"). Does your answer apply to only one value? I didn't write this detail in the question because I thought it wasn't important

Comment: There's a subtlety to `if variable[:1] in "aeiou":` that makes it differ from the first code example and the more self-documenting use of `startswith`: If `variable` is the empty string, it will evaluate to true, because the empty string is part of every string. You'd need to change it to `if variable and variable[:1] in "aeiou":` to make it equivalent to the other options.

Comment: Also, if you're not using `startswith`, and your using a literal of constant literals, as in this case, modern Python rewards using a `set` literal over a `tuple` literal as the number of items; `if variable[:1] in {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}:` will actually generate a `frozenset` at compile-time and reuse it each time, allowing `O(1)` `set` lookups instead of `O(n)` `tuple` lookups.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a `function` that checks if the string provided starts with a vowel:

```
def starts_with_vowel(str):
    return str.lower().startswith(("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")) # lower to be more general

variable1 = "open"

# check if it starts with a vowel
if starts_with_vowel(variable1):
    print("correct")
```

Answer (score 4):

It's silly, but you can [use `operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) to make a function that, called on any variable, will invoke the named method with the provided arguments, e.g.:

```
from operator import methodcaller  # At top of file

starts_with_vowel = methodcaller('startswith', ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))  # Done once at top level

# Done whenever you need to test a given variable
if starts_with_vowel(any_variable_producing_a_string):
    ...
```

To be clear, there's no reason to do this. It's just needlessly splitting up simple parts of program logic across your code rather than keeping it close together. In real code, I'd just do:

```
if variable.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')):
```

or if the set of prefixes to use is used in multiple places and long enough to be worth factoring out:

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')  # Done once at top level

# Done each place that needs the test
if variable.startswith(vowels):
    ...
```

Comment: I will never understand why people post these kind of answers (_it's silly_ / _there's no reason to do this_ etc). If you agree it's silly then don't suggest it at all.

Comment: @wim: There are real reasons to use these tools. This specific case does not benefit from it, (`starts_with_vowel(variable)` is no improvement on `variable.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))`), but it's a reasonable solution for say, using the `filter` function to do `filter(starts_with_vowel, list_of_variables)` (or any other function taking a predicate that it'll call on `str` it has access to, that the caller might now). Occasionally useful in *very* closely related scenarios, just not for the extremely specific case the OP gave.

Comment: It's not a very convincing reason. `methodcaller` may be useful when you have to pass it to some other function, in this answer it is used directly and just seems needless obfuscation / indirection. We should not post about vaguely related tools on every Q&A, or the number of answers melts up and the signal-to-noise ratio of SO decreases. I would say only when post the tool is clearly the best one _for the question_.

Answer (score 1):

```
def vowelstart(s):
    
    if(s[0].lower() in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")):
    
        return True
    
    return False
```

#Edited

Answer (score 1):

How about using regex instead of `startswith()`? A regular expression implementation could look like this:

```py
import re

variable1 = "open"

if re.match(r"^[aeiou]", variable1):
  print("correct")
```

Explanation of `r"^[aeiou]"`:

- `r" ... "` is a [raw string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-raw-strings/) often used for regex patterns.
- `^` simply means *starts with*.
- `[aeiou]` is a set of allowed characters.

I would probably wrap the regex in a function to make it more readable and *pythonic*. And compiling the pattern once outside the function may improve performance if the function is used often:

```py
import re

STARTS_WITH_VOWEL_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^[aeiou]", re.IGNORECASE)

def starts_with_vowel(text: str) -> bool:
  return True if STARTS_WITH_VOWEL_PATTERN.match(text) else False

if starts_with_vowel("open"):
  print("correct")
```

I hope this is helpful.